# Can I control how spring controller method arguments are instantiated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Consider the following interface/object hierarchy in a spring project:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    //method defenitions
}

@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
   //method implementations
}
```

I use `MyClass` in a controller method where it is read from the requests body:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/posturi", consumes = "application/json")
public void createEntity(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
    //handle request
}
```

The jackson library is used to read json data and convert it to a java object.

I would like to change the type of the parameter in the controller method from `MyClass` to `MyInterface`. This does not seem to work since the interface can't be instantiated with the `new` operator. But it *could* be created like this:

```
MyInterface instance = applicationContext.getBean(MyInterface.class);
```

Is it possible to make spring/jackson instantiate the object this way? I would like to do this so that my controller does not need to be aware of what implementation is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this now and the concept is quite simple but the implementation can be a bit tricky. As I understand it, you can annotate any type with `@RequestBody` as long as you provide a `HttpMessageConverter` that can convert from a http request to your desired type. 
So the solution is:

1. Implement a `HttpMessageConverter`
2. Configure spring so that your `HttpMessageConverter` is used.

The second part can be a bit tricky. This is because spring adds a bunch of default `HttpMessageConverter` that can handle common types such as strings, integers, dates and I want these to continue to function as usual. Another problem is that if jackson is on the path, spring also adds a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for generic json handling such as converting to concrete objects, maps and so on. Spring will use the first `HttpMessageConverter` it finds that claims to be able to convert to your type. The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` claims to be able to do so for my objects, but it is not able to, so it fails and the request fails. This could be considered a bug...

The chain that I wanted was:

1. Springs default `HttpMessageConverter`s.
2. My own `HttpMessageConverter`
3. The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

I found two ways to acheive this. First, you can declare this explicitly through xml.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <!-- All converters in specific order here -->
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The downside of this is that if the default `HttpMessageConverter` chain changes in later releases, it will not change for your configuration.

Another way to do it is to programatically insert your own `HttpMessageConverter` before the  `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;

    @Autowired
    private MyHttpMessageConverter myHttpMessageConverter;

    @PostConstruct
    private void modify() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = adapter.getMessageConverters();
        int insertLocation = messageConverters.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < messageConverters.size(); i++) {
            Object messageConverter = messageConverters.get(i);
            if (messageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                insertLocation = i;
            }
        }
        messageConverters.add(insertLocation, myHttpMessageConverter);
    }
}
```

The second alternative will continue to use the "default configuration" even if it changes in later releases. I consider it a bit hacky and not at all elegant but the reason I think it is a valid soulution is that there seems to be flaws in the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` claiming to be able to convert to types it cannot convert to. And also that you cannot explicitly add a `HttpMessageConverter` to a specific position in the chain.

For now I am going with the second option but how you do is up to you...

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with Converters. See documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html. Question is, how do you know which class you return by converter? Rather rethink your design to use POJOs in input.

Comment: The whole point is not knowing what the instance will be. As long as it implements MyInterface it will be allright.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of converters I don't see a clear possibility of how they could be used to inject and instance of MyInterface into a controller method without being aware of MyClass.

Comment: Should look like this: `class StringToMyInterface implements Converter<String, MyInterface> {

 public MyInterface convert(String source) {
  MyInterface i = new MyClass(); // which implements MyIterface
  return i;
 }

}` You always have to return instance of class